# Why does "echo 123 > a.txt b.txt" only create one file?

Tags: shell, echo, io-redirection

When I execute `echo 123 > a.txt b.txt` I expect to see `123` written to two files, `a.txt` and `b.txt`. But the actual result is that only one file is created. The content `123 b.txt` is written in the file called `a.txt`. Why does this happen?

Comment: see [step 5](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_01)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things are needed to make sense of this:

1. The redirection operator `>` only applies to a single file name. Anything after that file name is not part of the redirection; it's an additional argument to the `echo` command.
2. A lesser known fact is that redirections can be written anywhere in a command and have the same effect.

Putting these facts together, it means these commands are all equivalent:

```
echo 123 b.txt >a.txt   # traditional order
echo 123 >a.txt b.txt   # your command
echo >a.txt 123 b.txt
>a.txt echo 123 b.txt
```

All of them run the command `echo 123 b.txt` with output redirected to `a.txt`.

(I've condensed `> a.txt` to `>a.txt` to make it easier to see what `>` is binding to.)